# Why new Date(null) is returning this: Date 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z?

Tags: javascript, date, epoch

```
new Date(null)
// Date 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

How come when I type `new Date(null)` in JavaScript console I'm getting
`Date 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`?

Comment: [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Answer (score 37):

Because the ECMAScript 2017 standard says so?

The end of ECMA section [20.3.1.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) claims:

> The exact moment of midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970 UTC **is represented by the value +0**.

...which might make you say, "...but!, but!, I did not say +0, I said":

```
new Date(null)
```

Ok, so let's follow the standard on that one...

That Date constructor example goes to section [20.3.2.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-value), where item **3.b.iii** there says:

> 3.b.iii: Else, let V be ToNumber(v).

ToNumber is a hyperlink, so follow that to section [7.1.3](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-tonumber) where there is a number conversion table that shows:

> **Argument Type  |  Result**
>   Null                       | +0

Therefore:

```
new Date(null)
```

Effectively becomes:

```
new Date(+0)
```

Which is why you ultimately get:

> Date 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: what to do about it?

Comment: @Beki ... you could do something like: `new Date(Date.now())` or pass some other date value that can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently because that (Unix timestamp 0) is what a Date object is initialized to by default, eh?